# Set goal for leader NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am getting error in this. I need to ask leaders to move toward a goal. But getting error

> FACE expected input to be an agent but got the list [5 2] instead.
>   error while turtle 63 running FACE   called by procedure
>   LEADER-TOWARD-GOAL   called by procedure GO   called by Button 'go'

Here is the piece of code

```
patches-own [ is-visited? ]
turtles-own [ is-leader? goals ]
;globals [ number  ]
to setup
  let number 70
  ca
  ask patches [set is-visited? false ]
  ask n-of number patches  [sprout 1 [set size 1 set is-leader? false ]]
  choose-leader
  ask turtles [ set goals [ [15 10] [5 2] [0 0] ] ]
  ;tick
end

to go
; ask turtles with [  is-leader? ] [
 fd 1
 ;let target one-of goals

;lt random 20
;rt random 10
;set is-leader? false]
follow-leader
visited-patch
ask turtles with [ is-leader? ] [ leader-toward-goal]
;ask turtles  [ tick ]
end

to visited-patch
  if any? turtles-here [ set is-visited? true ]
end

to choose-leader
  ask max-n-of 7 turtles [ count turtles in-radius 6 ] [set is-leader? true set color red set size 0.7 ]

end

to follow-leader
  let nearby-leaders turtles with [is-leader? and distance myself < 30] ;; find nearby leaders
  if any? nearby-leaders [ ;; to avoid 'nobody'-error, check if there are any first
    face min-one-of nearby-leaders [ distance myself ] 
     ]
;  fd 1
end
to leader-toward-goal
  let target one-of goals
  face target
  if patch-ahead 1 = target [ print "target achived" ]
end
```

Need help with procedure

> leader-toward-goal

Answer (score 1):

Listen to NetLogo.  :-)
You set a turtles goals to a list of lists, and then you try to face one of those inner lists.  It does not make sense to face a list.  Just change the first line of `leader-toward-goal` to

```
let xy one-of goals let x item 0 xy let y item 1 xy let target patch x y
```

Or better yet, store patches rather than their coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to execute the primitive **face** with a list as input.
I guess that **goal** is a list of patches, try to instantiate it like:

```
ask turtles [set goals (list patch 0 0 patch 15 10 patch 5 2)]
```

instead of

```
ask turtles [set goals [ [15 10] [5 2] [0 0] ] ]
```

So you can say

```
face one-of goals
```

getting as input a patch instead of a list

Answer (score 0):

Others have suggested making the target a patch instead of a coordinate pair. That's probably good advice. But suppose you decide to stick with coordinates. In that case, you will need `facexy` instead of `face`, like this:

```
let target one-of goals
facexy (item 0 target) (item 1 target)
```